# RSpec instance_double respond_to? strange behavior

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I've got

```
let(:ssl_socket) { instance_double(OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket) }
```

Now I want to test if the object I have is an instance of OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket. I don't want to use be_an_instance_of matcher because I want my test to check more like "duck typing" way. So I want to know if object responds to 'ssl_version' method

```
it 'should change socket to ssl' do
    #do some stuff and set socket = ssl_socket
    expect(socket).to respond_to(:ssl_version)
end
```

It doesn't work

```
expected #<InstanceDouble(OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket) (anonymous)> to respond to :ssl_version
```

But if I do it using other matcher

```
it 'should change socket to ssl' do
    #do some stuff and set socket = ssl_socket
    expect(socket).to receive(:ssl_version)
    socket.ssl_version
end
```

then InstanceDouble will actually check if :ssl_version method is present in OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket instances. Is this a feature or a bug of RespondTo matcher? Should I use Receive matcher?

Comment: shouldn't `socket` be `ssl_socket` based on your `let` statement?

Comment: Yes, and I want to test that, i.e. after `do_some_stuff` `socket` (or `object.socket` to be precise) should be set to `ssl_socket` but it also could be `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instance_double` basically [creates a `Struct` instance](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/blob/4d842fefb82eaca7d33554746c1fb8c03738b068/lib/rspec/mocks/test_double.rb#L6) under the hood.

Out of the box it’s an object, that knows nothing about wrapped class. `receive` extends `stubs` attribute of it.

So yes, one should use `receive` in this case. To be more precise, one should not test `RSpec` itself and what you are doing is testing `instance_double` implementation.

Comment: Thank you, though it's kind of awkward for `respond` not to handle `instance_double` case (not to extend `stub` or pass arguments somehow). I mean there is no way someone wants to test `instance_double` implementation.